# Is my sample size vaild

Tags: sample-size

I am conducting a survey. Based on my calculation, I need a sample size of 300. However, I could only obtain 120 people to do my survey. what can I quote to justify the validity of my survey? CLT > 30? Is there any reference to support my sample size?

Comment: Validity depends on *how you obtained the sample,* not on sample size.

Comment: Probably all of us who have posted and commented (certainly me) seem to have assumed that you want to test something about the mean. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Without more info on how the sample size calculation was performed or the details about the study, there isn’t much we can say. That n>30 is usually applied to the t test as a justification for using a z statistic. It’s not a means of justifying a sample size.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

1) Do you have enough observations to give your test adequate power to reject the null hypothesis?

2) Do you have enough observations to believe your test statistic to be roughly normally distributed?

These are not the same, and don't confuse the ideas.

Only you can determine these answers. The first question can be answered with a power calculation. This is available in the `pwr` package in R. You also can specify how powerful of a test you want and then determine how big of a difference you can detect with that level of power.

The second question can be explored by examining your data. Graph it. Does it look normal? If it does, then you have your roughly normally distributed test statistic. If not, then it's on you to determine how non-normal your data look.

Comment: I am a little concerned about the implicit equation of the distribution of the data with the distribution of some unspecified test statistic as well as the emphasis on normal distributions.  Moreover, the issue really isn't power any more: the sample size is determined; power calculations are beside the point.  The issue is whether the sample is adequate to achieve some (unspecified) objective.